# Sending data from android to php using volley

Tags: php, android

The variables am sending to the server side can't seem to get there and i just can't figure out what the problem is. I get back a response from the PHP script saying that the POST is empty.

How its supposed to work

- insert comment in the alert dialog
- both the id and comment have to be    posted to the server side

please help!!!

```
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                /* Alert Dialog Code Start*/
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                final String id_number =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewIdnum)).getText().toString();

                alert.setTitle("Alert id: "+id_number); //Set Alert dialog title here
                alert.setMessage("Enter Your Comment here"); //Message here

                // Set an EditText view to get user input
                final EditText input = new EditText(context);
                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // convert the input to a string and show in a toast.
                        String reason = input.getEditableText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this,"Commenting...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        final String reason_key = input.getText().toString().trim();
                        //final String id_number_key = textview;

                        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.RESULT_URL,

                                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                                        Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                },
                                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                        Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put(TAG_IDNUM,id_number);
                        params.put(reason_key,reason);

                        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SearchActivity.this);
                        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

                    } // End of onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                }); //End of alert.setPositiveButton
                alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Canceled.
                        Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this,"Commenting cancled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }); //End of alert.setNegativeButton
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
                alertDialog.show();
   /* Alert Dialog Code End*/
                // End of onClick(View v)


            }




        });}
catch (JSONException e){}
}
```

Comment: if you don't get an error, try to put some logs to be sure that what you get from dialog isn't null

Answer (score 0):

1st you need to test if you php code is working, use postman to test your "api" if it works with postman your code should work.

In my opinion it's more a php fail than an android one.

Does your

```
 Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

print something ?

Comment: Yes it says undefined index id_number and undefined index reason. Which i assumed the variables are probably not being posted to the api

Comment: Does postman show something, add something in your database when you use it ?